Before computers, how did people ensure that their physical documents were safe?
Before computers, invention disclosures must have been done via physical documents and mail?
This doesn't seem safe at all.
Were there any protocols that were followed?

Paper has a shelf life measured in the hundreds of years. What makes you think digital documents are more reliable?

No, I meant that if you send a physical document disclosing your invention through post office, it can easily be intercepted, stolen, lost, sent to the wrong address, etc.

Which is why things like registered mail exist. I’m not trying to be sarcastic. People made do with the technology of the time. Digital is faster, but not necessarily safer.
